# Remove object if string in the list in Python of another file

Tags: python, json

I have a JSON file with multiple results:

```
[{
"objectID": 1,
"results": [
    {
        "model": "Audi Audi TT Roadster",
        "price_int": 2200,
        "rzc_result_url": "https://url1.jpg"
    },
    {
        "model": "Audi TT Roadster 1.8 T",
        "price_int": 2999,
        "rzc_result_url": "https://url1.jpg"
    },
    {
        "model": "Audi TT Roadster 1.8 T",
        "price_int": 2999,
        "rzc_result_url": "https://url1.jpg"
    }]
},
...
```

Obviously there are multiple objectID. I have another file with strings. For each objectID I want the script to be able to remove the result if the string is in the list
The exclude_model file:

```
{
    "1": ["1.8"],
    ...
}
```

The expected output:

```
[{
    "objectID": 1,
    "results": [
        {
            "model": "Audi Audi TT Roadster",
            "price_int": 2200,
            "rzc_result_url": "https://url1.jpg"
        }]
```

My code:

```
def excludeModels():
    with open('../json/exclude_models.json', encoding='utf-8') as data_file:
        r = json.loads(data_file.read())
        for item in data:
            results = item["results"]
            for k in results:
                objectID = item["objectID"]
                print(objectID)
                for d in r.get(objectID, []):
                    if d in results[k]['model']:
                        del results[k]
                        break

excludeModels()
```

Comment: Do you want to remove items from the json file, or from the in-memory dictionary?

Comment: From the in-memory dictionary I guess. In fact in my code the dictionary is created from a json file but I didn't precise it in this example.

Comment: `objectID = item["objectID"]`  Do you mean `objectID = item["id"]`?. Also where are you loading the other file??

Comment: could you explain the details of the exclusion criteria? I see no obvious relation between the inputs and the output.

Comment: I'm sorry there was an error and I edited it. in this example, there is the "1.8" string in two results so I want to remove each one.

Comment: You still have the `objectID` typo. You should be getting an error from that line.

Comment: Yes sorry I edited it, I made some changes for SO but this error is not in my code and it's not working

Comment: `k` is not a list index, it's the list element. And you shouldn't delete elements from a list while you're iterating over it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume `data` and `r` are following:

```
data = [
    {
        "id": 1,
        "results": [
            {
                "model": "Audi Audi TT Roadster",
                "price_int": 2200,
                "rzc_result_url": "https://url1.jpg"
            },
            {
                "model": "Audi TT Roadster 1.8 T",
                "price_int": 2999,
                "rzc_result_url": "https://url1.jpg"
            },
            {
                "model": "Audi TT Roadster 1.8 T",
                "price_int": 2999,
                "rzc_result_url": "https://url1.jpg"
            }
        ]
    }
]
r = {"1": ["1.8"]}
```

Then you can use the following function to filter data dictionary. Be careful, that `id` is integer in `data` dictionary, however it is a string in `r` dictionary! That is one a problems in your code above.

Also, be careful how you delete values in lists! When you iterate over list you delete values from, there can be an issue you do not iterate through the whole list, because you delete the values under your hands. That is why I firstly collect the indices I want to delete into `indices_to_del`. And after that I iterate over this list in reverse order to ensure I will delete the values I really want to delete.

```
def excludeModels(data, r):
    for item in data:
        results, objectID = item["results"], item["id"]
        unwanted_strings = r.get(str(objectID), [])
        indices_to_del = []

        for i, item_res in enumerate(results):
            if any([(u_s in item_res['model']) for u_s in unwanted_strings]):
                indices_to_del.append(i)

        for res_i in indices_to_del[::-1]:
            results.pop(res_i)
```

The result is following:

```
>>> excludeModels(data, r)
>>> print(data)
[{'id': 1, 'results': [{'model': 'Audi Audi TT Roadster', 'price_int': 2200, 'rzc_result_url': 'https://url1.jpg'}]}]
```

Comment: You might want to explain why the loop at the end is in reverse.

Comment: @Barmar, thank you for noticing me. I edited my answer.

Answer (score 0):

There's no `objectID` key in the JSON, it's `id`.

You don't need to set `objectID` each time through the `k` loop.

You can use the `any()` function to test all the exclusions in one call.

```
def excludeModels():
    with open('../json/exclude_models.json', encoding='utf-8') as data_file:
        r = json.load(data_file)
    for item in data:
        results = item["results"]
        objectID = item["id"]
        print(objectID)
        if objectID in r:
            exclusions = r[objectID]
            for k, val in results.items():
                if any(d in val['model'] for d in exclusions)
                    del results[k]
```